# Webpack + typescript: Conserve class type

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle a library written in typescript. The library is intended to work on client side. After checking webpack documentation, I created the following test:

the main class is as follows:

```
import { RenderService } from "./render.service";

export class Grid {

    renderService: RenderService;
    constructor() {
        console.log("constructed");
        this.renderService = new RenderService();
        this.renderService.render();
    }
}
```

the render service class

```
export class RenderService{
    constructor(){
        
    }
    render(){
        console.log("renderred");
    }
}
```

tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "module": "es6",
      "target": "es5",
      "jsx": "react",
      "allowJs": true
    }
  }
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/ts/via-grid.ts',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
};
```

What I want is to be able to instantiate the Grid class in a javascript script so what I've done after I used webpack to create a bundle is:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
</head>

<body>
   <!--Some content-->>
</body>
<!--Bundeled solution-->
<script src="../dist/bundle.js"></script>
<script src="./script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Where script.js is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vg = new Grid();
});
```

and I was expecting the console to output

> Constructed
> Rendrerred

But instead I get

> ReferenceError: Grid is not defined

So where is the issue?

Comment: The issue is: Webpack bundle everything into a module, not expose everything as global. To use a module, you must import it.

Comment: Any workarounds? importing a module with the settings of the example is not posible

Comment: Why don't you write your `script.js` inside the webpack bundle, such as inside your `via-grid.ts`?

Comment: Because the script.js is just a test app. What I want is to create a Grid library that can be used in any javascript based project (in the question is the script.js) by instantiating a Grid class and work with it. Same as ChartJs

Comment: I never did it, so I can't give you a definitive answer. However, you should look at webpack `Output` option: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/ . E.g: libraryTarget `umd` and globalObject `window`